# SQL - parent - child relationships in different records

Tags: sql, parent-child

I've been given a SQL table that has a parent-child relationship that I'd like to present in a readable format.

The main columns involved are Drawer, Folder, Document. Each Drawer can have multiple folders associated to it, and each folder can have multiple documents associated to it. However, the Folder and Document are not listed in the same record.

This table contains item types, and a folder and document are both considered items. To associate them, the table assigns the itemnumber of the folder to the parentID in the document record.

For example:

```
DrawerID   ItemID    ParentID    Type    Name  
  1          1          0       Folder   Folder 1  
  1          2          0       Folder   Folder 2  
  1          3          0       Folder   Folder 3  
  1          4          0       Folder   Folder 4  
  1          5          1       Document Document A  
  1          6          1       Document Document B   
  1          7          1       Document Document C 
  1          8          2       Document Document A  
  1          9          3       Document Document A  
  1          10         3       Document Document B
```

What I'm looking for is an output similar to this:

```
Drawer 1
    Folder 1
        Document A
        Document B
        Document C
    Folder 2
        Document A
    Folder 3
        Document A
        Document B
```

The part that I'm stuck on is how to tie the ParentID to the ItemID. Would the best approach be some sort of union? recursive programming into a new table? I'm not a SQL person - I just cut and paste bits of queries, so please use little words :)

Comment: Is this a table you're stuck with or could you break them into the entities?  Otherwise it will be a lot of self-joins.

Comment: SQL 2008 and I'm stuck with the tables as they are.

Comment: If it's SQL 2008 then the query I posted below should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should work, tested OK in SQL Server on your data. Basically it's creating two pseudo tables in the query to represent the Folder and Document entities then joining together on the parent relationship:

```
SELECT Folder.DrawerID, Folder.FolderId, Folder.FolderName, Doc.DocumentId, Doc.DocumentName
    FROM 

    (Select DrawerId, ItemId AS FolderId, ParentId, [Name] AS FolderName FROM Drawers WHERE [Type] ='Folder') Folder,

    (Select DrawerId, ItemId AS DocumentId, ParentId, [Name] AS DocumentName FROM Drawers  WHERE [Type] ='Document') Doc

    WHERE Doc.ParentId = Folder.FolderId
    ORDER BY DrawerId, FolderName, DocumentName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going two levels deep, it may make sense to create data like this:

```
DrawerID    FolderID    ItemId    Description    ...
```

The folder itself would have an item id of null or zero.

Then you could query with:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY DrawerID, FolderID, ItemID
```

Comment: Ah, I wish I could redo the table - however, it's beyond my control on the structure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no recursion in standard SQL.

However, there are some patterns that solve the kind of problems you have, one of them is [nested sets](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4155/Improve-hierarchy-performance-using-nested-sets).

Comment: Just want to add that certain SQL flavors (like T-SQL with CTE) do support recursion.

Comment: @mfussenegger Agreed. I changed the first statement to make it more true :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use self-joins if you know how many levels you are dealing with. In a self join, you basically pretend the same table is a new table and alias it (T2, or whatever) with a different name. This example may get you started:

Incidentally your data has an odd issue, a single row should exist with a type Drawer ID =0 for the concept to be complete. The code below has to be changed or that error fixed

```
select 

T1.name,
T2.name,
T3.name //etc repeat as needed and below

from myTable T1

LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable T2 ON
  T2.ParentID= T1.ItemID

LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable T2 ON
  T2.ParentID= T3.ItemID

group by 1,2,3
```

Comment: You are correct - there is a row for the Drawer with an ItemID of 0, and a ParentID of NULL. One thing I'm not sure of, in reading your coded - where it T3 defined?